# Chrome - Configure screenshot hot key

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

Are there any way of adding short key for capturing screenshots in Google Chrome?

[image]

Comment: I need this as well. I don't want to lose focus on an input when taking the screenshot, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Using DevTools to force focus on the input isn't giving me the proper styling either.

Comment: I opened https://crbug.com/743765 to request that a standard hotkey be created for this since 174309 is more focused on customizing existing shortcuts. First we would need to have a default shortcut to be able to customize it.

Comment: @Splaktar It's now possible by enabling _focused page_ from the Rendering tab: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65188771/5846045

Comment: What is the use case of the shortcut? Why was it needed in the first place? Is it to keep the focus on the UI while taking a screenshot? We need more context in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work on the DevTools team. There's no keyboard shortcut for it, and there's no way to add custom keyboard shortcuts.

But you can access it from the Command Menu.

1. Open the [Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#command-menu).
2. Start typing `Screenshots` and select `Capture full size screenshot`.

Comment: It's a pity that you can't configure any of the four screenshot options with a hotkey.  They seem to be listed under Settings->Shortcuts but with no apparent way to setup a shortcut. FWIW Mozilla have a screenshot icon you can add to the menu. Click on it and you get an area screenshot - simple.

Answer (score 5):

Long list but fastest execution when learned:

1. press CTRL+SHIFT *(keep them pressed)*
2. press i *(opens Chrome development tools)*
3. press p *(opens the Command Menu)*
4. release CTRL+SHIFT
5. write "**re s**" *(selects "Captu**re s**creenshot" command)*
6. press Enter *(executes the command and downloads the captured screenshot)*

Variants of step n. 5:

- write "**cfu**"  *(selects "**C**apture **fu**ll size screenshot" command)*
- write "**caph**"  *(selects "**Cap**ture area screens**h**ot" command)*
- write "**cnod**"  *(selects "**C**apture **nod**e sreenshot" command)*

Comment:  Best available workaround for keyboarders

Answer (score 2):

To take a screenshot **while the page having the focus** (hence the need for shortcuts):

1. In the DevTools, open the [command menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/command-menu), type `Rendering`, and select "Show Rendering":

   [image: Chromium "Command Menu" typing "Rendering" dark theme]
2. In the Rendering tab, enable **☑️Emulate a focused page**:

   [image: Chrome devtools panel Rendering with "Emulate a focused page" highlighted]
3. Now you can take screenshots as described in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#screenshots) but without the need to use shortcuts:

   [image: Chrome devtools taking screenshot with emulated focus on the OpenUI5 page]